# Cannot root Acer Iconia A500 running on Android 4.0.3

Tags: bootloader, root-access, adb

I have an Acer Iconia A500 here that is supposed to be rootable. But I tried and tried. But nothing made the job.

I tried using ADB and Fastboot, but it said to me that it can't run the command because it's locked. Then I tried to use

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

but then it said (cmd):

```
... OKAY [0.166s] finished. total time: 0.167s
```

then I reboot into bootloader again and then (cmd):

```
sending 'recovery' (5360 KB)...
FAILED (remote: (00000002))
finished. total time: 0.176s
```

and then in the tablet:

```
Bootloader v0.03.12-ICS: Starting Fastboot USB download protocol
Fastboot: Not support the command in Lock mode
Failed to process command download:0053c000 error(0x2)
```

even though I already unlocked the device

Does somebody know what's happening here? The third thing I tried was ICS_rooting, with no success. I'm running Android 4.0.3 if that helps any.

PS: I also tried to use GingerBreak, but GingerBreak is for Ginger, and I have Ice Cream Sandwich, as this is one of the last ones that Acer sold.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4039271

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same problem, and gingerbreak will load forever
But another method do work : https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/full-root-for-a50x-ics-4-0-3-leak-simple-method.1546593/